# How to get Id from feedback button selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, iframe, css-selectors

In the https://store.liverpoolfc.com/ home page there is feedback button on right side, I managed to click and open feedback modal but cant get Id of rating button, I tried to add id, classname, xpath, csselector of input in feedback but its not working.

Here is my code:

```
By acceptCookies = By.id("onetrust-accept-btn-handler");
By feedbackHomeBtn = By.id("nebula_div_btn");
By frame = By.cssSelector("iframe[id*='kampyleForm']");
By label = By.xpath("//label[contains(@class,'rating-label')][contains(.,'8')]");
By submitBtn = By.cssSelector(".panel-footer-web .submit-btn");
By closeBtn = By.cssSelector("button[aria-label='Close Survey']");



public void acceptCookies(){
    try{
        driver.findElement(acceptCookies).click();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exceptions Caught" + e.getMessage());
    }
}


public void feedbackFuncionality(){
    try{
        driver.findElement(feedbackHomeBtn).click();
        driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(frame));
        driver.findElement(label).click();
        driver.findElement(submitBtn).click();
        driver.findElement(closeBtn).click();
        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exceptions Caught" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

And code in test.java

```
    @BeforeTest
public void beforeTest(){
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    driver.get(url);    
}


@Test
public void feedbackClick() {
    FeedBackPage feedBackPage = new FeedBackPage(driver);
    try {
        feedBackPage.acceptCookies();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        feedBackPage.feedbackFuncionality();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@AfterTest
public void afterTest(){
    driver.quit();
}
```

I need to open feedback modal and click on rating btn between 1 and 10. Can anyone give me some hints how to get this id? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feedback scoring form is inside an iframe. So, after landing on that page and closing the cookies banner and clicking the feedback button you need to switch into that iframe. There you can select the feedback score, send the feedback and close the dialog as shown in the code below. Finally you need to switch to the default content.
The following code works

```java
driver.get("https://store.liverpoolfc.com/");
WebdriverUtils.clickVisible(driver,By.id("onetrust-accept-btn-handler"));
WebdriverUtils.clickVisible(driver,By.id("nebula_div_btn"));
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("iframe[id*='kampyleForm']")));
WebdriverUtils.clickVisible(driver,By.xpath("//label[contains(@class,'rating-label')][contains(.,'6')]"));
WebdriverUtils.clickVisible(driver,By.cssSelector(".panel-footer-web .submit-btn"));
WebdriverUtils.clickVisible(driver,By.cssSelector("button[aria-label='Close Survey']"));
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

The method I used here `clickVisible` is implemented as following:

```java
public static boolean clickVisible(WebDriver driver, By locator, int timeout) {
    try {
        Wait<WebDriver> wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(locator)).click();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ConsoleLogger.error("Failed to click on element" + e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}
```

```java
public static boolean clickVisible(WebDriver driver, By locator) {
    return clickVisible(driver, locator, 30);
}
```

Comment: Exceptions Caughtno such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//label[contains(@class,'rating-label')][contains(.,'8')]"} got this error, not sure why when I crtl+f in inspect element it is pointing to right label but it throws this error when running test :/

Comment: Are you sure you switched into the iframe?

Comment: Did you tested this? I tried like you wrote but it cant find frame element :(

Comment: Yes, I run this code several times, it works.

Comment: It work just need to change int to Duration and add in second method Duration.ofSeconds(x)

Comment: I use Selenium 3, so it is `int` there, but if you are using Selenium 4 you need to change it to `Duration`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the rating button with css selector

```
By.cssSelector("input[value='x']")
```

where x = 0, 1, 2...

Comment: adding just the value of input its not recognizing element, I added also like this input[name='rating', value='9'] and its not working, it cant find the element

Comment: A ti si nas :D, ne mogu staviti value samo, mora name ili id pa value, jel? ne znam jel ispravno sto sam ovo gore pisao, al ne moze da nadje element

Comment: "input[value='1']" je css selektor za element tipa "input" koji ima atribut "value='1'".

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to click on the element which is **inside cross-origin iframe**

You need to switch the frame and then click on the element

you can switch using following way

```
driver.switchTo().frame("Your_frame_ID");
```